# Facebook Opengraph Action does not work at all times

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I created a Facebook OpenGraph App which was integrated with my website http://liveofofo.com everything worked fine but the problem is that not every read action triggers a post to timeline, as a matter of fact, it may not work in days meanwhile, I have the same Opengraph plugin and settings on another site (ghanamovie.org) and it works perfectly, all read actions triggers a post to timeline

I have done a lot of troubleshooting but I still can't get what exactly the problem is, I'll appreciate any help suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the source code for [the first article on the page](http://liveofofo.com/gossip-column/mbgn-2012-isabella-ayuks-secret-runs/).

The Open Graph meta tags are repeated several times on the page (and are not in the <head> section of the file).

Take a good look at the structure of your code and use [the Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://liveofofo.com/gossip-column/mbgn-2012-isabella-ayuks-secret-runs/) to see if Facebook approves of your syntax.

If there is a problem when you are posting the Open Graph action, log the error message. It will probably tell you why the post failed.